# How would I create a copy of an entire spreadsheet when a specific cell has been edited?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The title says it all. When the specific cell A9 is edited I need to create a copy of the entire spreadsheet inside of an *Invoice* folder. The cell is an invoice number, so when an invoice number hits the sheet I need to create a copy of it so all invoices can be collected at the end of the day and can be printed/manipulated. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome. Questions on this site should be about specific programming questions and it's advisable to include a brief description of your search/research efforts. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Comment: You can get started with by getting familiar with [onEdit() trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit). This trigger runs automatically when a user changes the value of any cell in a spreadsheet. With regard to copying you can use the [copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination).